# Real time loop control in python

Tags: loops, real-time-updates

I am working on a project to control switching of gates for an inverter with python in Raspberry Pi.

There is this sequence of pins I need to turn off and on in a cycle to achieve this with some time delay inbetween for adjusting the frequency. But as I wanna develope my code to next level, now I would like to adjust the delay in loop in real time to adjust the frequency ,I am trying to change the speed of the execution of the loop without stopping the loop itself in real time, is there any way to do this in python?